# Traverse through div elements using tab index

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm creating a Memory Game and I want to be able to select and flip the different cards using the keyboard. Right now I'm using tab index on the cards (which are DIV elements), but the problem is that when traversing over the cards using TAB I'm not selecting the cards in the correct order, rather it's jumping around when selecting. I have tried setting the tab index value to different values, such as the first card having the lowest value and the last card having the highest value.

**So, my question is:** How can I traverse the cards with the tab key in the correct order?

Note, I'm only using vanilla javascript.

[image: My Memeory Game]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the running code or a simplified example showing the problem

Comment: The code is over 200 lines of code, and wasn't sure if it would be appropriate to paste that all in here. But I can show some images of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, try to  provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Here's one: sort the elements on their `tabindex` property value:

```js
document.querySelector(`[tabindex="1"]`).focus();
const sortedDivsOnTabIndex = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[tabindex]`)]
  .sort((divA, divB) =>
    +divA.getAttribute(`tabindex`) - +divB.getAttribute(`tabindex`));

// result
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = sortedDivsOnTabIndex
  .map(div =>
    `tabindex ${div.getAttribute(`tabindex`)}, content "${div.textContent}"`)
  .join(`\n`);
```

```css
#tiContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12rem;
}
pre {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 13rem; 
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div id=tiContainer>
  <div tabindex=3>t3</div>
  <div tabindex=4>t4</div>
  <div tabindex=8>t8</div>
  <div tabindex=6>t6</div>
  <div tabindex=1>t1</div>
  <div tabindex=9>t9</div>
  <div tabindex=2>t2</div>
  <div tabindex=10>t10</div>
  <div tabindex=7>t7</div>
  <div tabindex=5>t5</div>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```